# Outputting array to string

Tags: powershell, powercli

I have an object array returned by the expression:

```
@{N="Members";E={";", $_.Vmids|%{(get-view -id $_).name}}}
```

I want this to output to a string so that I can then output it to excel. If I throw an ft on the end I get a table value but I'd like to have a join statement so that it can be outputted to a list to match my other function outputs thus giving me a single formatted XLS for this documentation. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the entire command?

Comment: I would just wrap part of the code and use a -join statement to make a string. Like `($_.Vmids|%{(get-view -id $_).name}) -join ', '`

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. Are you only importing the names into Excel, or other data as well? Please provide an example of the structure of your input and desired output.

Comment: Get-DrsRule -Cluster * | select Name,Cluster,Type,@{N="Members";E={";", $_.Vmids|%{(get-view -id $_).name}}}

I want the VMId field to be translated to something useful, in this case VM name, and outputted in a string instead of a table.

Comment: This did it:  ($_.Vmids|%{(get-view -id $_).name}) -join ', '

once I deleted the extraneous ";" which was probably messing up a lot of things and I'm not entirely sure where it came from.

So the final command became: Get-DrsRule -Cluster * | select Name,Cluster,Type,@{N="Members";E={($_.Vmids|%{(get-view -id $_).name}) -join ', ' }}

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to create a string of the names joined with a `,`.

```
@{N="Members";E={";", ($_.Vmids | Foreach-Object {(get-view -id $_).name} | Sort-Object) -join ', ' }}
```